# Find combination of sets which sum up to a specified result

Tags: c#, console, set, hashcode, overloading

Example input :

> A) 1, 2
>
> B) 2, 8
>
> C) 7, 8
>
> Required Result : 8, 10

The output from the program with this input should be A + C.

Few notes :

1. We can only combine 2 sets.
2. There must always be exactly one pair (or a single set) which sums up to the specified result.
3. Input will always be in this format **x,y**.

**Set**

```
internal class Set
{
    protected bool Equals(Set other)
    {
        return Number01 == other.Number01 && Number02 == other.Number02;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Set) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Number01*397) ^ Number02;
        }
    }

    public int Number01 { get; }
    public int Number02 { get; }

    public Set(int number01, int number02)
    {
        Number01 = number01;
        Number02 = number02;
    }

    public static Set operator +(Set set1, Set set2)
    {
        return new Set(set1.Number01 + set2.Number01, set1.Number02 + set2.Number02);
    }
}
```

**Static void Main**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Length : ");
        int inputLength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] inputSets = new string[inputLength];
        Set[] sets = new Set[inputLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"Enter set #{i + 1} : ");
            inputSets[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.Write("Enter the expected result : ");
        string[] answer = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
        Set requiredResult = new Set(int.Parse(answer[0]), int.Parse(answer[1]));

        for (int i = 0; i < inputSets.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] numbersFromSet = inputSets[i].Split(',');
            sets[i] = new Set(int.Parse(numbersFromSet[0]), int.Parse(numbersFromSet[1]));
        }

        foreach (Set set in sets)
        {
            if (Equals(set, requiredResult))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First set : " + set.Number01 + " " + set.Number02);
                Console.WriteLine("Result : " + requiredResult.Number01 + " " + requiredResult.Number02);
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sets.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sets.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Equals(sets[i] + sets[j], requiredResult))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("First set : " + sets[i].Number01 + " " + sets[i].Number02);
                    Console.WriteLine("Second set : " + sets[j].Number01 + " " + sets[j].Number02);
                    Console.WriteLine("Result : " + requiredResult.Number01 + " " + requiredResult.Number02);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You use the `Equals` method in `Main` in some `if`s like `if (Equals(set, requiredResult))`. Did you forget to post this one?

Comment: No error checking in split or int.Parse.  Ask for desired result first and if you don't allow negative can throw some out.   If you are only going to return the first you can check against prior as it is entered.   Can use HS to eliminate duplicates.  Rather than add and compare.  subtract once and look for specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually don't like the `Tuple` but in this case it looks like a perfect example where I think you'd be much better off if you used one instead of the `Set` (that I'd name `Pair`).

The `Tuple` already can do all the equality stuff so you don't need to write it yourself or you can derive your class from the `Tuple` so that is supports the `+` operator.

```
class Pair : Tuple<int, int>
{
    public Pair(int item1, int item2) : base(item1, item2) {}

    public static Pair operator +(Pair left, Pair right)
    {
        return new Pair(left.Item1 + right.Item1, left.Item2 + right.Item2);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var pair1 = new Pair(1, 2);
var pair2 = new Pair(1, 2);
var pair3 = new Pair(1, 3);

(pair1.Equals(pair2)).Dump(); // True
(pair1.Equals(pair3)).Dump(); // False
```

Answer (score 1):

> `if (Equals(set, requiredResult))`

As @t3chb0t points out, you're calling `Equals` rather than `[set object].Equals` in `Main`. In effect you are saying `this.Equals(set, requiredResult)`, `this` being the class containing `Main`. The `object` class implements `Equals`, and all classes inherit from `object`, so what you're ultimately calling is `object.Equals`. In other words, you've gone to the trouble of overriding `Equals` in your `Set` class but you're not using it. This will lead to unexpected results given you expect equality to be determined by the content of the properties, rather than by reference (which is what `object.Equals` will do for classes).

Another issue is you override `Equals` but don't override the equality operators. This means that `set1.Equals(set2)` will return a different result than `set1 == set2`, which is surely undesirable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the fact that i didnt overload the != & == operators but since im not using them i decided they will just take more space. I picked t3chb0t's answer because using his approach not only that it shortens the code but also does all the work i might need in the future.